# Remove an Action from Workflow Rule using Change Set

Tags: workflow, deployment, change-set, workflowrule

I have an existing Workflow Rule with 3 actions. I remove one action in a sandbox. Create a Chnage Set with only this Workflow Rule (not action I removed). Upload to Production. Check the source of the Workflow - only 2 actions are stated. Deploy. Still 3 actions in Production.
Is this a bug or a feature?
What is the point to upload workflow and still have it not changed? No, Last Modifie Date is changed but not the Workflow Rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove an Action from Workflow Rule through Change Set the Action which should be removed must be present in the Change Set. So you deploy Workflow Rule + Action you want to remove. Just tested. It worked. Weird logic, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it's possible to remove workflow actions through change sets or the metadata api. It's not mentioned anywhere in particular in Salesforce docs, although Gearset does mention this in their support docs as they're a deployment tool.

https://docs.gearset.com/en/articles/2872107-removing-workflow-rule-actions

You'd be better off manually removing the action in Production through the UI.

Comment: I did it manually. But the confusion here is because I think about this kind of deployment as layout changes, where you remove a field from layout. Like the same... Now I'm not sure I can remove field from layout through Change Set...

Comment: It is a bit different. Workflow Rules and Workflow Actions are technically two different things which is why I think the issue comes up where you cannot remove actions from the rule.

Comment: I understand that they are technically and logically different things. But from my logic I assumed that I need to modify only Workflow Rule entity, as I want to modify only Workflow Rule. Adding Workflow Action to a Change Set along with Workflow Rule seams odd to me as the same Workflow Action can be used in other Workflow Rules, so changing WR should not depend on WA. And it wasn't as WA was not touched but should be present in CS in order for WR to be modified.